# Como imprimir arquivo sem abrir?

Tags: c#, itextsharp

Meu sistema gera um PDF criado em iTextSharp e uso o seguinte código para abrir o mesmo:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(nomeArquivo);
```

`nomeArquivo` é o endereço do arquivo PDF.

Como faço pra mandar o arquivo direto pra impressora sem precisar abrir?

Comment: De maneira geal não é possível, nem tem vantagem alguma fazer isto. O que dá para fazer é usar alguma coisa pronta que abra e imprima. Você não está vendo, mas está sendo aberto.

Comment: @bigown, a ideia é a seguinte. O usuário agenda uma consulta pra um paciente e o sistema pergunta: deseja imprimir comprovante? caso positivo já manda pra impressora, sem precisar abrir o pdf e clicar no botão de impressão.

Comment: Isso não muda nada, qual é a diferença de abrir e em seguida imprimir?

Comment: Apenas um pedido dos usuários (pra não ter que clicar duas vezes). Caso não seja possível fazer, irei deixar como está

Comment: Tire a necessidade de clicar duas vezes na sua aplicação, você tem controle sobre ela.

Comment: não entendi bem, pode explicar melhor?

Comment: Acho que agora entendi, você está abrindo um leitor de PDF externo. Não tinha pensado nessa gambiarra. Na verdade nem é um problema de C# então. Aí tem que ver como mandar esse leitor que está sendo usado fazer a impressão sem intervenção do usuário e mandar esse comando da forma como está fazendo.

Comment: eu crio o arquivo usando iTextSharp, e abro o mesmo usando o leitor de PDF padrão através do código acima.

Comment: Como eu disse não é problema de C#, nem de programação, é saber como mandar esse leitor imprimir automaticamente. Você sempre coloca *tags* que não são do problemas então confunde.

Comment: @bigown, desculpe, ainda estou aprendendo.

Comment: se puder, dá uma editada no meu post e põe uma tag mais adequada

Comment: Na verdade acho que esse nem é problema de programação, é saber manipular esse leitor específico, como mandar o comando você sabe.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, @Virginio Novic me passar o código

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma forma de enviar direto para impressora, mas, tem que instalar no computador o *Acrobat Reader (ou similar)*.

***Exemplo***:

<sup>**Configure as 4 primeiras linhas mediante configurações local do seu computador**</sup>

```
string NomedaImpressora = "Microsoft XPS Document Writer";
string CaminhoeNomedoArquivo = @"C:\Temp\Exemplo.pdf";
string CaminhoDoAcrobat = @"C:\Adobe\Acrobat 11.0\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe";
string DiretorioTemp = @"c:\Temp\Pdf";

ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = CaminhoDoAcrobat;            
startInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/t \"{0}\" \"{1}\"",
                                       CaminhoeNomedoArquivo,
                                       NomedaImpressora);
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = DiretorioTemp;

Process process = Process.Start(startInfo);
process.WaitForInputIdle();
process.CloseMainWindow();
process.Close();
process.Dispose();
```

o processo funciona de maneira até satisfatória pelo testes realizados.

<sub>***Referencia:*** [Forum MSDN - Imprimir PDF direto p/ impressora](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/875e95e5-8b87-41bd-90d9-b5fd9d44104d/imprimir-pdf-direto-p-impressora?forum=vsvbasicpt)</sub>

Comment: obrigado, é isso mesmo que estou precisando ^^

Comment: Bom levei um voto negativo, tem algum problema a resposta?

Comment: oxe, que estranho... nem vou comentar o que estou pensando. Mesmo assim, obrigado mesmo pela ajuda, foi de grande valia.

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo sem problemas rapa... tranquilidade na nave! relaxa acontece.